# How to generate CSS3 Shapes

Tags: html, css, shapes

I have a shape in my photoshop layers, I'm attaching the image of that shape. Will you please write how to generate it from CSS3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use css :after effect

```
<div class="shape"></div>

.shape {
width: 100px; height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
background-color: #fc0;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
text-decoration: none;}

.shape:after {
content: "";
width: 100px; height: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: -50px;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index: 3;}
```

Answer (score 1):

.img-shape { width: 367px; height: 623px; background-color: #bababa; display:block; margin-left: 50px; position: relative; z-index: 2;} .img-shape:after { content: ""; width: 562px; height: 840px; background-color: #FFFFFF; position: absolute; top: -108px; right: -470px; border-radius: 50%; z-index: 3;}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background layer container and place overlay shape container in same parent. Please check below code. I hope it will help you.

```css
.container{width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#ccc;
position:relative}

.circle{width:300px;
height:540px; background:#fff;
position:absolute;
left:52%;
top:-10px;
border-radius:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```